# No WS-Security header found

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am trying to consume a service which demo url is as follow

[https://demo.unicommerce.com/services/soap/uniware13.wsdl?facility=01][1]

when i add this service and try to use this in my code as follow

```
using abc;
public partial class unicommerce : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        unicommerce u = new unicommerce();

        UnicommerceClient us = new UnicommerceClient();


        Customer c=new Customer ();
        PartyAddress pa=new PartyAddress ();
        pa.StateCode="25";
        pa.Pincode="302017";
        c.BillingAddress=pa;
        PartyContact p=new PartyContact ();

        c.Contact=p;
        c.CSTNumber="123";
        c.CustomerCode="ABC";
        c.Name="example";
        c.PAN="CYKPS7842";
        c.Website="http://mywebsite.in";

        CreateCustomerRequest cr = new CreateCustomerRequest();
        cr.Customer = c;
        us.CreateCustomer(cr);

    }
}
```

Its throwing error

```
No WS-Security header found

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: No WS-Security header found
  [1]: https://demo.unicommerce.com/services/soap/uniware13.wsdl?facility=01
```

I asked to the person who made this service regarding this , he said to me that this service is created on apace with java code.

As far i have idea this error is related to user name and password (authentication) , but not getting where should i pass those credentials .

Comment: getting same error while trying to do unicommerce integration. Did you figure out the problem????

Comment: you can pass the credentials at

           us.ClientCredentials.UserName.username="username";
            us.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password="password";

Answer (score 2):

U can use the standard .Net WSS Implementation from Microsoft.Web.Services2

```
using Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.Utility;

UsernameToken token = new UsernameToken(username, password, passwordOption.SendHashed);          

Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.Utility.Timestamp ts = new Timestamp();

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

XmlElement token = token.GetXml(doc);
XmlElement timestamp = ts.GetXml(doc);

string stoken = token.InnerXml;
string stimestamp = ts.InnerXml;
```

and so on, works perfect.

Microsoft.Web.Services2.dll can be found here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FC5F06C5-821F-41D3-A4FE-6C7B56423841&displaylang=en

Comment: XmlElement token = token.GetXml(doc); what is doc here ?

Comment: XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

Comment: i also added how to get the string value

Comment: type or namespace  UsernameToken could not be found ? are you missing any reference ?

Comment: U need to reference Microsoft.Web.Services2 to your project the token is in Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.Tokens

Comment: here u can get the lib http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FC5F06C5-821F-41D3-A4FE-6C7B56423841&displaylang=en

Comment: btw.if u don't need nonce u can also use wcf to generate the token

Comment: Is it possible for you to find solution with my current code... Thanks in advance

Comment: @rahularyansharma: Note that not all webservice implementations can be easily implemented by add adding reference / web reference and using the auto generated proxy classes and methods to call endpoints. I'm not sure if the webservice u try to implement supports that. For simple services with simple requests it can be much more effective to implement them by building the request by hand. My suggested method is based on this thought. Building the xml, no matter how.

Comment: Then use the UsernameToken object to generate the xml node(s) for wss username/token authentification and add it to the xml u generated/built before and post the data to the endpoint. U have to set the correct http headers etc. This cannot be done "on the fly" u need time to learn and understand what u do and why u do it and so on ... :-)

Comment: Thanks . I will try my best to learn all things .. Really thanks for your time .

Comment: These links are now: 404 :(

Answer (score 1):

You have to know the security requirement to communicate with the web service, and then add the security headers to your code
check an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.services2.security.tokens.usernametoken.aspx)

Comment: i already checked that example but don't understand how to use that code into my code ?

Comment: You don't need to use this code exactly, First check what is the security requirement for the service you are dealing with, then add the proper security header. in case you have plain username token in the service, you can use this example. You need to use UsernameToken, get the SoapContext of your service proxy, then set the Timestamp and add the username token to it as in the example